# How to loop through and update all objects in an Firebase Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

What is the best approach to looping through an observable collection of objects, updating each object?

I have tried the following, but when I call the method `setActive()` either nothing happens or I get to much happening.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProgramService {
  private programs$: FirebaseListObservable<IProgram[]>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private auth: AuthService) {
    private const path = `/programs/${auth.id}`;
    this.programs$ = af.database.list(path);
  }

  getPrograms(): Observable<IProgram[]> {
    return this.programs$;
  }

  setActive(currentProgram: IProgram) {
    console.log('setActive: ' + currentProgram.$key);
    this.programs$.map(programs => {
      programs.map(program => {
        let key = program['$key'];
        if (key === currentProgram.$key) {
          this.programs$.update(key, {"active": true});
        } else {
          this.programs$.update(key, {"active": false});
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'programs',
  templateUrl: 'app/program-list.component.html'
})
export class ProgramListComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  programs: IProgram[];

  constructor(
    private _ProgramService: ProgramService, 
    private _router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._ProgramService.getPrograms()
      .subscribe(
        programs => this.programs = programs,
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

  setActive(program: IProgram) {
    this._ProgramService.setActive(program);
  }
}
```

From my component I subscribe to the `programs$` observable using `getPrograms()` and list all programs in my template and indicate which program is active. By clicking the button on another row than the active I call `setActive()`.

Template:

```
<div class='panel panel-default'>
  <table class='table table-hover' *ngIf='programs && programs.length'>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor='let program of programs'>
        <td (click)='gotoDetail(program)'>
          <h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>{{ program.title }}</h4>
          <p class='list-group-item-text'>{{ program.description }}</p>
        </td>
        <td class='text-right text-nowrap'>
          <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' 
              *ngIf='program.active'>Current program</button>
          <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' 
              *ngIf='!program.active' (click)='setActive(program)'>Set current</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If I run the above nothing happens. It does not even hit `console.log()` in my method.

If I try to change the method, say I change `this.programs$.map(programs => {` to `this.programs$.forEach(programs => {` then I get objects from Firebase and the update logic runs well. The problem then is that I get too much data, I get every object several times, like this `[obj1] .. [obj1],[obj2] .. [obj1],[obj2],[obj3] .. etc` and thereby updates each object several times. The next time I run the method it doubles up on the results, and the third time I run it it will get so much data that my browser halts and gives up.

Any ideas, input, tips, tricks, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i'm struggling with the same issue. the thing is that the observable that return from firebase comes in a "pyramid" way (e.g. {obj1}, {obj1, obj2}, {obj 1, obj 2, obj 3}).

a crude way to solve it would be to map the response that comes from the subscription. pay attention that the first "map" is rxjs map, the second "map" is regular es6 map.

`returnMappedPrograms() : Observable {
return this.programs$.map(programs => {return programs.map( (program) => {//do some thing to program..// return program}) 
}`

though it solves the problem (at least in my case) - it's really excessive (the second map run over each object several times). I think a better solution would be to recreate the observable, but i'm still researching on that matter